# Qt tabbing order skipping custom widget contents

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, tabbing

**I have set tab order in Qt to go through the UI in a logical order for the user** - but upon running the software and testing I found it was skipping custom widgets from the UI. 
It's meant to go into the custom widgets and go through the different combo boxes/spin boxes and other various UI objects for the different cases.

Code example for setting focus policy, (if not doing it through Qt UI):

```
this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::WheelFocus);
```

Wheel focus is the correct type of focus for the objects in the custom widgets but should be initially tabbed into.